# How many watts would I need to get CO2 from 30 °C to 4000 °C in 1 hour

Tags: thermodynamics

**Scenario:** After reading some articles on new sorts of ways to deal with $\ce{CO2}$ in the atmosphere, a question came to mind: If I had 100 kg of $\ce{CO2}$, and I would like to heat it up from 30 °C to 4000 °C in a given period (lets say 1 hour), how much energy would I need? What would that be in watts? And from there, assuming a solar panel with 20 % efficiency for 1 m² (therefore 200 watts/hour), what would be the area of solar panels needed to reach heat the $\ce{CO2}$?

**Obs:** From my very forgotten knowledge of Chemistry from high school, I found the specific heat for $\ce{CO2}$ should be 1000 to 1800 kJ/(kg K), and from this page http://www.heatweb.com/techtips/useful.html I got a formula and tried calculating it, but my units are probably all wrong, because the value was considerably low. I then multiplied 100 kg * 1500000 * 3970 °C. With the energy value, I divided by time (1 hour) to have the output in watts.

**Obs2:** I know that I am forgetting or do not know about many other limitations (such as the dissociation above a certain temperate). I also know that it would be inefficient and very costly, but would nonetheless like to find out the values, to try and figure what would be necessary for this procedure.

**Question:** Is this a viable way to do this calculation? What else should I consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I approached this in a similar way utilizing the heat capacity of $\ce{CO2}$ over a temperature range.

An estimation can be made by approximating the change in enthalpy of $\ce{CO2(g)}$ over a given temperature range. This can be accomplished through the integral form for changes in Enthalpy:

$$\Delta{H} = \bar{H_1} - \bar{H_2} = \int_{T_1}^{T_2}C_p(T)\,\mathrm dT$$

Which has units of [energy/mass].

Often times, the function $C_p(T)$ for certain gases and liquids will be tabulated in textbooks or chemical databases (such as NIST). In this case, I will utilize a function for the $C_p(T)$ of $\ce{CO2}$ in two temperature ranges (300–1200 K, 1200–6000 K)$^1$:

$$C_p(T)=A+BT+CT^2+DT^3+\frac{E}{T^2}$$

Range 1 (300–1200 K) coefficients:

$A=24.997,$ $B=55.187,$ $C=-33.691,$ $D=7.948,$ $E=-0.137$

Range 2 (1200–6000 K) coefficients:

$A=58.166,$ $B=2.720,$ $C=-0.492,$ $D=0.039,$ $E=-6.447$

Next, we can obtain the energy required for this temperature change by multiplying $\Delta{H}$ by the mass of $\ce{CO2}$ we're interested in, such that:

$$Q = m_\ce{CO2}\,\Delta{H} =  m_\ce{CO2}\int_{T_\text{initial}}^{T_\text{final}}C_p(T)\,\mathrm dT = m_\ce{CO2}\left[\int_{T_1}^{T_2}C_p(T)\,\mathrm dT + \int_{T_2}^{T_3}C_p(T)\,\mathrm dT\right]$$

Evaluating the integrals (keeping in mind that A, B, C, and D will change based on the temperature range in this case) yields:

$$m_\mathrm{CO2}\times7.266\times10^{12}\ \mathrm{\frac{J}{mol}}$$

$$\frac{100}{0.04401}\ \mathrm{\frac{kg}{\frac{kg}{mol}}}\times7.266\times10^{12}\ \mathrm{\frac{J}{mol}} = 1.651\times10^{16}\ \mathrm J$$

In watts, this value becomes:

$$\left(1.651\times10^{16}\ \mathrm J\right) \left(\frac{1}{3600}\ \mathrm{\frac{h}{s}}\right) = 4.560\times10^{12}\ \mathrm W$$

Calculating the solar-panned area required:

$$A_\text{panels} = \frac{4.560\times10^{12}}{200}\ \mathrm{\frac{W}{\frac{W}{m^2}}} = 2\times10^{10}\ \mathrm{m^2}$$

Source [1]: “Carbon Dioxide.” Carbon Dioxide, National Institute of Standards and Technology, webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C124389&Mask=1#Thermo-Gas.